# How to get the URL of image using Google Custom Search Engine

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-custom-search

I'm trying to build a custom image search using Google's CSE and I'm facing some difficulties getting the URL from the result box.

I have already created a new search engine and implemented the code on my web page.

[image: Result of searching dogs with my custom search engine]

The results are showing properly and the search engine is working as intended.

Now what I would like to get is:

1. Avoid opening the picture on another window
2. Click on the image and get the real URL of the picture (not encrypted)
3. Display selected url on alert window

What I found so far exploring the source code is that the result image items URL links are encrypted and not showing the real URL of the image.

The following code is the result of searching the same dog using my custom search engine with Google's API and Google image search web page.

- The img result using my custom search engine

  `<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQmjyo4iFP_SQ-a2u7piFW8hZ_J4CEtDMF6_dE8Ev-RvqcZlA93DIo6uQo" title="How dogs contribute to your health and happiness" class="gs-image gs-image-scalable" style="width: 126px; height: 84px;">`
- The img result using Google's web image search

  `<img class="irc_mi" src="https://cdn1.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/322/322868/golden-retriever-puppy.jpg" onload="typeof google==='object'&amp;&amp;google.aft&amp;&amp;google.aft(this)" alt="Image result for dogs" width="529" height="353" style="margin-top: 0px;" data-iml="1552180024897">`

Note that src parameter in one is encrypted and not in second one. If I do the same search on Google image I can get the real URL from the src.

So my question is: How to get the real image URL using Google's CSE? Is there any way I can get the original URL?

I have gone through this the documentation https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list but is not clear to me how to implement the *Optional query parameters*. Maybe with "linkSite" query parameter?

Best regards and have a nice day!

Comment: I suspect this URL may be encrypted by design, as getting the unencrypted URL could potentially be used for less positive reasons than was intended, so this might not be possible to do directly. You may get more useful answers if you can give some context for your higher-level goal, so alternative approaches can be suggested.

Comment: I'm creating a Virtual Reality 3D editor using A-Frame over Threejs library and I would like to give the user the opportunity to search images on the editor so they can add their image search to the 3D scene. Actually I can add any google image to the 3D scene using image URL I get from google image search. The issue is that they have to get the URL outside the editor and then paste it into it, where the best solution should be building a custom image search on the editor and then add the image from there. I hope this clarifies a little bit more the issue.

Comment: I would guess they specifically don't want you doing this for copyright reasons, just like how they removed [this feature](https://9to5google.com/2018/02/09/google-images-features-getty-deal/) a while back. But I can't find any concrete sources of this related to the API, so I could be wrong.

Comment: I understand the reasons why they made that decision and I totally agree. In any case, there should be an option on the CSE where you can find images without copyright choosing a feature similar to "Search images labeled for reuse" (Google image search offers that option) or something similar. I will try to approach the solution in another way. Thanks for the help and advice John!

Comment: I think you can get all related sites and search on them for the original picture : items[].image.contextLink. check if the title of the original image and the image of google are the same. It's not really good, but it's a possible solution.